SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module - tmi-utils import
I am currently trying to create a chat overlay for twitch handmade through js, html, and css. When researching ways to implement emotes into my strings I came across tmi-utils. On the documentation page it says to use:
import { getEmoteAsUrl, parseEmotesInMessage } from 'tmi-utils';
When I use this along with the provided example code:
JS:
const client = new tmi.Client({ /* tmi options */ });
client.connect();

client.on('message', (channel, tags, message, self) => {
  // The emotes object is a mapping of emote id to a list
  // of it's positions in the message string. For example,
  //
  // message: staying on the map is hard LUL LUL wow
  // emotes : { 425618: ['27-29', '31-33'] }
  const { emotes } = tags

  // `parseEmotesInMessage` splits the message up into strings and emotes
  const parsedMessage = parseEmotesInMessage(emotes, message);

  // Then you can render the message with emotes however you like
  const message = document.createElement('span');

  // Safely append each part
  parsedMessage.forEach(({ type, value, raw }) => {
    if (type === 'emote') {
      const img = new Image();
      img.src = getEmoteAsUrl(value);
      img.alt = raw;
      img.title = raw;

      message.append(img);
    } else {
      message.append(value);
    }
  });

  document.querySelector('.message-list').append(message)
})

Here is my HTML code that implements a webside tmi.js:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Twitch chat</title>
    <script src="tmi.min.js"></script>
    <script src="overlay.mjs"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

When doing this I get the SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module.
When I researched this issue I read that it was due to how modules are imported. With this in mind I followed the solutions of adding "type": "module" to my package.json file as well as changing my file type to an .mjs file but I am still getting the error. As well I have tried adding "type": "module" to my html script block but I receive a 'null' due to being blocked by CORS policy.
I'm very new to JS, Node.js, etc... So if you have any tips on top of solutions feel free to let me know!

The easiest way is probably to use a bundler like Vite and bundle the JavaScript code.

There's no import statement in the code you posted

@Pointy It's above the example code. They're together I was just putting an individual snippet for the import code they gave me.

Well the .mjs suffix does not work for browsers. You have to add type=module to your <script> tag to tell the browser to interpret your script as an ES6 module.

@Pointy I mentioned in the description that I attempted to do that and got an error due to the CORS policy.

Well that's not CORS policy, it's the Content Security Policy, and you can fix that. However, importing a script from your own domain is not going to cause any kind of security issue.

@Pointy I know it has been a minute since my last reply. I wanted to thank you for your help! You pointed me in the right direction to get my issue resolved.
